# How to use pure css selector to select hidden element

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<td class="col" style="display:none">AAA
      <span prop="1" class=" clear-icon " style=""></span>
</td>
```

I want to use pure css to hide text "AAA" to show span btn.
Is there a way to do it in pure css?

Comment: please clarify more about the `style="display:none"`, is that your original HTML code or just your attempt to solve your problem?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want _"AAA"_ to be hidden but the `<span>` to show. Is this correct? If so, I don't believe that is possible. As far as I know, a nested/child element cannot be visible if the containing/parent element is hidden. You could try putting _"AAA"_ in a span as well. Then you could hide only the one `<span>` containing the _"AAA"_...

Comment: so I have html string generator in the back-end, it decides whether the td element should hide or not. I wanna use pure css to select the hidden element

Comment: @War10ck Yes, that's pretty much what I want. It is some legacy code, so I don't want to change the html a lot. wrap text with span requires DOM change. That's why I don't want to do that

Comment: @Zen it's still confusing, what is the hidden element you want to mean? the `td` or the text node `AAA`?

Comment: @KingKing by default the entire td is hidden, now I want to hide only text node "AAA"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your design is not really responsive, I mean you can just need to set fixed font-size for the inner `span`, I think we have a clean solution like this. The idea is to set `font-size` of the `td` to `0`, it will hide the text node completely:

```
.col[style*="display:none"] {
  display:table-cell!important;
  font-size:0;
}
.col > span {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/755HM/)

Comment: @War10ck thanks, however it has a limitation with using relative font-size (I also mentioned that in the answer), sometimes fixed/absolute font-size is acceptable. Hope it suits the OP's case.

Comment: Take into account that this selector will find `display:none`, but **not** `display: none` (with a space).

Comment: @Andrew yes, that's right. However the answer was given to the specific code of the OP. Also the main idea here is still valuable. The OP should not use inline style like that, he could however declare a `hidden` class and then the `.col[style*="display:none"]` can become `.col.hidden` which should work expectedly (no unintentional  exception)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't criticizing your solution but simply mentioning something to take into account, because yesterday I was scratching my head when the selector wasn't working as I expected. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `visibility` property but this will reserve the space for text "AAA":

```
.col {    
    visibility:hidden;
}

.clear-icon {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Also, if you can't remove `display:block !important;` from your `td` tag just add `!important` rule in CSS

```
.col {
    display:block !important;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col {
    visibility:hidden;
}

.col span {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <td class="col">
        AAA <span>Show Me</span>
    </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vLNEp/4/

```
<table><tr><td class="col"><span class="hidden">AAA</span>
      <span prop="1" class="clear-icon"></span>
</td></tr></table>

.col .hidden {position:absolute;top: -9999px; left: -9999px;}
```

Comment: looks like if we have more text (a long text other than just `AAA`), it won't look good like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/7bM95/27/

Comment: Updated my answer. It simply wont work even with setting the element to hidden. It will take up space.

Comment: however I think the OP's HTML code is fixed (it's generated by some engine, so he can't edit it, he can just edit the CSS file). So your updated code won't be what the OP can use.